# Cloud Run/Build artifacts buckets are created with Fine Grained access policy by default

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, access-control, bucket

When using Cloud Run Jobs (I'd assume any service running Cloud Build under the hood as well), dedicated artifact buckets are created. Their naming is usually something like: `us.artifacts.project.appspot.com`. With directory `/containers/images/` and files like `sha256:<checksum>`.

Is there a way to **prevent** such buckets from having *Access Policy* set as *Fine Grained* by default? Instead they should use *Uniform*, which is the one recommended. ([ref1-cis_v120_5_2](https://hub.steampipe.io/mods/turbot/gcp_compliance/controls/control.cis_v120_5_2), [ref2](https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.6.2/checks/google/storage/enable-ubla/), [ref3](https://www.trendmicro.com/cloudoneconformity-staging/knowledge-base/gcp/ResourceManager/enforce-uniform-bucket-level-access-constraint.html))
Not only such access policy is hard to manage on a larger scale (in my case at least), but SCC is reporting findings on such buckets.

Most preferably I would like to set a flag on org or folder level making such Cloud Build Buckets be always created with Uniform access policy.
I have **not** attempted to update the access policy manually (neither I've considered automated update) as this does not sound like an optimal solution to a problem which shouldn't exist in the first place.
A very insecure workaround would be muting SCC alerts from category 'BUCKET_POLICY_ONLY_DISABLED' related to appspot.com buckets (if that field would even be accessible for muting rules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce this organization policy on your project (or your folder or the entire organization: `Enforce uniform bucket-level access`

[image]